# in SAS, is it possible to declare 2 hash tables in the same data step?

Tags: sas, hashtable, datastep

I'm able to declare 1 hash table like this:

```
data DALY1;
    * set lengths ;
    length Germ $10 Category1 $50 Category2 $50 AgeGroupDALY $10 Gender $2 value 8;

    * make link to hash table ;
    if _n_=1 then do;
        declare hash h1(dataset:'modelData');
        h1.definekey ('Germ', 'Category1', 'Category2', 'AgeGroupDALY', 'Gender') ;
        h1.definedata('Value');
        h1.definedone();
        call missing(Germ, Value, Category1, Category2);
    end;
run;
```

but when I declare 2 like this:

```
data DALY1;
    * set lengths ;
    length Germ $10 Category1 $50 Category2 $50 AgeGroupDALY $10 Gender $2 value 8;

    * make link to hash table ;
    if _n_=1 then do;
        declare hash h1(dataset:'modelData');
        h1.definekey ('Germ', 'Category1', 'Category2', 'AgeGroupDALY', 'Gender') ;
        h1.definedata('Value');
        h1.definedone();
        call missing(Germ, Value, Category1, Category2);

        declare hash h2(dataset:'states');
        h2.definekey ('Germ') ;
        h2.definedata('stateList');
        h2.definedone();

    end;
run;
```

I get:

> ERROR: Undeclared data symbol stateList for hash object at line 194 column 3.
>   ERROR: DATA STEP Component Object failure.  Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.

I'm wondering if it is even possible to declare 2 hash tables (or more, I will need 3) at the same time.
If the answer is yet, what am I doing wrong?

I can't find any example of this anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create multiple Hash tables in one DATA STEP.

Refer to: [This Forum Paper](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/029-2008.pdf)   or  [This SESUG paper](http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2011/BB08.Lafler.pdf)

You did not define the variable 'stateList'.
Add the variable 'stateList' to your LENGTH statement.

Comment: Damn I forgot the length :/  Thanks for spotting this!